# UseEffect or throwing logic in the functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React. I know that UseEffect can be useful for keeping related data in sync with each other.

Example 1:

The code below updates **calendarDate** and **inputDate** whenever the prop **rawDateInput** gets updated.

```
const DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YY';

type Props = {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    required?: boolean;
    value?: Date | undefined;
    readOnly?: boolean;
};
const DatePicker: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ name, value: rawDateInput, label, required, readOnly }) => {
    const inputId = name.replace(/[\W]+/g, '_');

    const [calendarDate, setCalendarDate] = useState<Date | null>();
    const [inputDate, setInputDate] = useState<string>('');
 
    useEffect(() => {
        const momentDate = moment(rawDateInput);
        setCalendarDate(momentDate.toDate());
        setInputDate(momentDate.format(DATE_FORMAT));
    }, [rawDateInput]);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Label htmlFor={inputId} text={label} />{required && <span className='text-danger'>*</span>}
                <input
                    id={inputId}
                    name={name}
                    value={inputDate}
                    readOnly={readOnly}
                    placeholder={DATE_FORMAT}
                    maxLength={8}
                />
                <Calendar value={calendarDate}  />
        </Fragment>
    );
}
export default DatePicker;
```

Example 2:

The code snipper below accomplishes the same thing as Example 1, but it simply puts the logic inside of the functional component instead of calling the useEffect hook.

```
const DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YY';

type Props = {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    required?: boolean;
    value?: Date | undefined;
    readOnly?: boolean;
};
const DatePicker: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ name, value: rawDateInput, label, required, readOnly }) => {
    const inputId = name.replace(/[\W]+/g, '_');

    const momentDate = moment(rawDateInput);
    const calendarDate = momentDate.toDate();
    const inputDate = momentDate.format(DATE_FORMAT);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Label htmlFor={inputId} text={label} />{required && <span className='text-danger'>*</span>}
                <input
                    id={inputId}
                    name={name}
                    value={inputDate}
                    readOnly={readOnly}
                    placeholder={DATE_FORMAT}
                    maxLength={8}
                />
                <Calendar value={calendarDate}  />
        </Fragment>
    );
}
export default DatePicker;
```

My questions are:

1. When we have data that is dependent on the prop, should we use UseEffect (Example #1) or simply putting the logic in the functional component (Example #2)?
2. Does UseEffect provide any performance gains in this case? like minimizing the number of reloads.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches work. The second one is probably a bit clearer to read, since there's no state at all, and the values are calculated directly from the props, but having the calculation be in the main function body instead of in the effect callback will mean that the calculation will be called on every render, rather than only when the prop changes.

But there's an even better way to achieve that without using `useEffect` or state, which is to use `useMemo`:

```
const momentDate = useMemo(() => moment(rawDateInput), [rawDateInput]);
const calendarDate = useMemo(() => momentDate.toDate(), [momentDate]);
const inputDate = useMemo(() => momentDate.format(DATE_FORMAT), [momentDate]);
```

> Does UseEffect provide any performance gains in this case? like minimizing the number of reloads.

It will minimize calls to `moment`, but it'll also increase the number of re-renders, since a prop change will result in the effect callback running, a state change, and another render. A potential disadvantage of `useEffect` is that it's not instantaneous - state updates take a bit of time. This occasionally results in screen flashing and asynchronous issues with child components.

Answer (score 0):

> When we have data that is dependent on the prop, should we use
> UseEffect (Example #1) or simply putting the logic in the functional
> component (Example #2)?

Storing derived values from passed props into local state is actually an anti-pattern in React. It is prone to synchronicity issues (i.e. stale state). Just consume the passed props directly and render the result.

> Does UseEffect provide any performance gains in this case? like
> minimizing the number of reloads.

No. If anything it adds more renders since an additional render cycle is necessary to render based on the updated local state. If you are looking to possibly boost performance you can memoize the computations in the second snippet using the `useMemo` React hook with a dependency on the specific props used.